# ¿Como hacer boton toggle? VB NET

Tags: vb

lo que quiero es que dandole click al boton, estando de color blanco, se ponga verde, y despues al volver a darle click, se ponga como antes, y asi sucesivamente

EN Visual Basic

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y sobre todo veas [ask], edita tu pregunta agregando el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, así será mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Si solamente deseas hacer un cambio de color de un boton simulando un toggle

Puedes utilizar `Select Case` para validar el color actual del color y cambiarlo con el evento `Click()`

Puedes utilizar las propiedades BackColor de el boton con colores RGB y colores access de la siguiente lista
[Colores Access](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm)

Tengo un ejemplo aqui de como podrias implementar tu boton

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'''Evento de Click

'''Selecciona la expression que deseas buscar
Select Case CommandButton1.BackColor

    '' En caso que tenga este Backcolor (16775416) cambialo por verde (4231485)
    Case 16775416
    Col = 4231485

    '''Se deja color (16775416) como default
    Case Else
    Col = 16775416

End Select 

CommandButton1.BackColor = Col  
End Sub
```

Aqui te dejo tambien un ejemplo de un Toggle donde puedes simplemente usar un IF en el evento de Click del Toggle

```
Private Sub CheckBox()
''' Color por default de la propiedad BackColor
CheckBox1.BackColor = RGB(240, 255, 240)

''Si se activa el toggle cambia de color
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
End Sub
```

Tambien podrias intentar especificar mas tu pregunta
De que tipo de botones estas hablando?

Esto lo hice en Excel